# Pandas - Fastest way indexing with 2 dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, optimization

I am developing a software in Python 3 with Pandas library.

Time is very important but memory not so much.

For better visualization I am using the names **a** and **b** with few values, although there are many more:

**a** -> 50000 rows

**b** -> 5000 rows

I need to select from dataframe **a** and **b** (using multiples conditions)

```
a = pd.DataFrame({
'a1': ['x', 'y', 'z'] ,
'a2': [1, 2, 3],
'a3': [3.14, 2.73, -23.00],
'a4': [pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan]
})

a
  a1  a2     a3  a4
0  x   1   3.14 NaN
1  y   2   2.73 NaN
2  z   3 -23.00 NaN

b = pd.DataFrame({
'b1': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'k', 'l'],
'b2': [2018, 2019, 2020, 2015, 2012] 
})

b
  b1    b2
0  x  2018
1  y  2019
2  z  2020
3  k  2015
4  l  2012
```

So far my code is like this:

```
for index, row in a.iterrows():
    try:
        # create a key
        a1 = row["a1"]

        mask = b.loc[(b['b1'] == a1) & (b['b2'] != 2019)]

        # check if exists 
        if (len(mask.index) != 0): #not empty
            a.loc[[index], ['a4']] = mask.iloc[0]['b2']

    except KeyError: #not found
        pass
```

But as you can see, I'm using **for iterrows** that is very slow compared to other methods and I'm changing the value of the DataFrame I'm iterating, that is not recommended.

Could you help me find a better way? The results should be like this:

```
a
  a1  a2     a3  a4
0  x   1   3.14 2018
1  y   2   2.73 NaN
2  z   3 -23.00 2020
```

I tried things like this below, but I didnt made it work.

```
a.loc[ (a['a1'] == b['b1']) , 'a4'] = b.loc[b['b2'] != 2019]
```

*the real code has more conditions

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I benchmark using: **iterrows**, **merge**, **set_index/loc**. Here is the code:

```
import timeit
import pandas as pd

def f_iterrows():
    for index, row in a.iterrows():
        try:
            # create a key
            a1 = row["a1"]
            a3 = row["a3"]

            mask = b.loc[(b['b1'] == a1) & (b['b2'] != 2019)]

            # check if exists
            if len(mask.index) != 0:  # not empty
                a.loc[[index], ['a4']] = mask.iloc[0]['b2']

        except:  # not found
            pass

def f_merge():
    a.merge(b[b.b2 != 2019], left_on='a1', right_on='b1', how='left').drop(['a4', 'b1'], 1).rename(columns={'b2': 'a4'})

def f_lock():
    df1 = a.set_index('a1')
    df2 = b.set_index('b1')
    df1.loc[:, 'a4'] = df2.b2[df2.b2 != 2019]

#variables for testing
number_rows = 100
number_iter = 100

a = pd.DataFrame({
    'a1': ['x', 'y', 'z'] * number_rows,
    'a2': [1, 2, 3] * number_rows,
    'a3': [3.14, 2.73, -23.00] * number_rows,
    'a4': [pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan] * number_rows
})

b = pd.DataFrame({
    'b1': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'k', 'l'] * number_rows,
    'b2': [2018, 2019, 2020, 2015, 2012] * number_rows
})

print('For: %s s' % str(timeit.timeit(f_iterrows, number=number_iter)))
print('Merge: %s s' % str(timeit.timeit(f_merge, number=number_iter)))
print('Loc: %s s' % str(timeit.timeit(f_iterrows, number=number_iter)))
```

They all worked :) and the time to run is:

> For: 277.9994369489998 s
>
> Loc: 274.04929955067564 s
>
> Merge: 2.195712725706926 s

So far Merge is the fastest.

If another option appears I will update here, thanks again.

Comment: Shouldn't row `2` have `a4` 2020 in your expected output?

Comment: Is `mascara.iloc[0]['b2']` a constant (the same for every iteration of the for-loop)?

Comment: You're right, I included the '2020' thanks.
About 'mascara'(word in portuguese sorry), I corrected to 'mask'.
But anyway, 'mask' will change because it depends of the a1 which depends on the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
a.merge(b[b.b2!=2019],left_on='a1',right_on='b1',how='left').drop(['a4','b1'],1).rename(columns={'b2':'a4'})
Out[263]: 
  a1  a2     a3      a4
0  x   1   3.14  2018.0
1  y   2   2.73     NaN
2  z   3 -23.00  2020.0
```